# Twitter search: OR with Tags - but how?

Tags: search, twitter, twitter4j

I cannot search the twitter API for tweets which contain one of multiple tags.

Like: `q="#tag1 OR #tag2 OR #tag3"`

If I leave away the hashes and only search for words, the OR-ing works. For tags they don't.
When I only use spaces, the search terms will be AND-ed, what shrinks the result...

I use the twitter4j library with:

```
Twitter rest = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
Query query = new Query();
query.setQuery("#win | #fail");
QueryResult result = rest.search(query);
```

Isn't it possible, or didn't i use it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use OR operator instead of "|":

```
query.setQuery("#win OR #fail");
```

See available Twitter search API operators here:

[Using the Twitter Search API](http://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)

Answer (score 1):

Might just be easier to use [twitter's REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api). You'll want to use the search query. [Here's an example](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23LA%20OR%20%23NYC%20OR%20%23Boston%22&callback=?) search url searching for #LA, #NYC or #Boston. Note the spaces and #s are all [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding). Just pop a URL like that into a getJSON call like below and you can easily extract your values from the returned JSON object as in the example.

```
var requestedData = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23LA%20OR%20%23NYC%20OR%20%23Boston%22&callback=?"
$.getJSON(requestedData,function(ob)
{
  var firstTweet = ob.results[0].text;
  var firstTweeter = ob.results[0].from_user;
}
```

From there it's just a matter of looping through your results and pulling the appropriate fields which are all outlined in the JSON file if you simply visit that example search link in your browser! I don't know this TwitterFactory API but its possible they haven't updated to Twitter's new API or they're just not URL encoding appropriately. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah OR you could just try what Shcheklein said and see if that works with TwitterFactory. I thought you had already tried that but I may be misreading.